# Making Apache http client threadsafe

Tags: scala, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am on Scala 2.10.2 and want to implement a thread-safe http provider using Apache http client 4.2.5, here's what I have done

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
import scala.concurrent.Future

object AsyncHttpProvider {
  import org.apache.http.client._
  import org.apache.http.client.methods._
  import org.apache.http.impl.client._

  val httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient

  private def get(query: String) = {
    val httpget = new HttpGet(query)
    val brh = new BasicResponseHandler
    httpclient.execute(httpget, brh)
  }

  def getResponseBodyAsJValue(query: String): Future[JValue] = Future(parse(get(query)))
  def getResponseBodyAsJsonString(query: String): Future[String] = Future(get(query))
}
```

Since I am using `Future`, I want to make sure that the code is thread-safe, is it?

Answer (score 1):

It's documented that the DefaultHttpClient is threadsafe (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html), but you don't need to recreate it inside your 'get' function. Usually, client creation is quite expensive and it can be more efficient to instantiate one or more pooled instances to be shared across threads. In this case, you could create or inject the instance into your object and reference it within the Future. The only new thing to create would be the Method and response handler.

Speaking of async calls, you may also consider looking athttp://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/examples.html

Comment: Good point on not needing to re-create the `DefaultHttpClient` inside `get`, I have reflected the change in my question. So it looks like it is thread-safe now.

Comment: As it turns out, this isn't doing what I thought it would, with every client connection, I need to consume the response body before I can reuse the connection for another request,so back to my original code until I implement some kind of pooling.